# Doctrine ArrayCollection Big O

Tags: php, doctrine

I just wanna know big O of the doctrine array collection methods: `count()` and `isEmpty()`.

Is `count()` `O(n)` and `isEmpty()` `O(1)`?

Comment: In which programming language? The question is labeled php, but php does not name functions in lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Yes, in PHP https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.html

Comment: oh i see, sorry i didnt know